# How to enable social media sign-on, when creating user through API management REST API call

Tags: azure, azure-api-management

I have created some APIs in API management and using it thrugh REST API of API management. Now In my Application, I want to use social media authentication, when I am creating a user. e.g. In my asp.net mvc Application, I have a option to login with facebook/google. I have configured these apps correctly and user is getting authenticated as well. However after authenticating the user successfully, how do I pass Auth Type as "Facebook", when I am creating the same user in Azure API management through REST API call.

It works perfectly fine when using developer console, however I am not getting how to pass Auth Type attribute (as "Facebook") when creating user through API Management REST API.

Answer (score 0):

On Invite user, it is not possible to provide a Social Media Sign-in, you can only do basic authentication.

You can raise a user voice for this feature here: https://feedback.azure.com/forums/248703-api-management